# Regularized Incomplete Beta Function

Tags: statistics, beta-function

I try to solve this property of Regularized Incomplete Beta Function. How can you solve a statement : 
$I_x (a,a) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} I_{4x(1-x)}(a,\frac{1}{2})  $ where $1/2 \leq x \leq 1$.

Some definitions :
$I_x (a,b) = \frac{B(x;a,b)}{B(a,b)}$ with B(x;a,b) is incomplete Beta function and B(a,b) is Beta function.
I tried to use substitution rule with z = 1 - x. But it doesn't go any further.
Could someone give me idea more please ?

Comment: Can you give the definition?

Comment: here you can find the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: I meant if you post the definitions and your attempts then people would engage with the question more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definitions you wrote
$$\text{lhs}=\frac{B_x(a,a)}{B(a,a)}$$
$$\text{rhs}=1-\frac{B_{4 (1-x) x}\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Now, for $ \frac 12 \leq x \leq 1$
$$\frac d {dx}\text{[lhs-rhs]}=\frac{(1-x)^{a-1} x^{a-1}}{B(a,a)}-\frac{2^{2 a-3} (4 (1-x)-4 x) ((1-x) x)^{a-1}}{\sqrt{1-4 (1-x) x}
   B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
Since $ \frac 12 \leq x \leq 1$, the last term simplify and write
$$\frac{2^{2 a-1} ((1-x) x)^{a-1}}{B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
$$\frac d {dx}\text{[lhs-rhs]}=\frac{(1-x)^{a-1} x^{a-1}}{B(a,a)}-\frac{2^{2 a-1} ((1-x) x)^{a-1}}{B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Divide by $(1-x)^{a-1} x^{a-1}$ to get
$$\frac{\frac d {dx}\text{[lhs-rhs]} } {(1-x)^{a-1} x^{a-1} }=\frac{1}{B(a,a)}-\frac{2^{2 a-1}}{B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}=0$$ by the properties of the beta function.

So, for $ \frac 12 \leq x \leq 1$, $\text{[lhs-rhs]}$ is a constant. For $x=1$ for example
$$\text{lhs}=\frac{B_1(a,a)}{B(a,a)}=1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \text{rhs}=1-\frac{\Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right) B_0\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2
   \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (a)}=1$$ Then, the identity.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is great !

Comment: @GiaLe. If my answer is good, may be you could accept it . Cheers :-)

Comment: .I have a question. Why lhs and rhs are differentiable ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question.